# Simple wrapper scripts spawning 100s of bash processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have this kind of GCC multilib wrapper set up:

```
#file: gcc
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gcc -m32 "$@"
```

which essentially just wraps a 64-bit multilib gcc to act as a non-multilib 32-bit gcc. When I build something (like binutils for example), this spawns hundreds of `bash` processes, until even `fork` fails. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you named your script gcc, put it in the path, and then called it recursively.  Either name your script something different or use an explicit path to the gcc executable you actually want to use.

Comment: super like!   :-)

Answer (score 6):

[Kevin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23334/simple-wrapper-scripts-spawning-100s-of-bash-processes/23337#23337) has already found the core issue, namely that you're calling your own script recursively.

A simple way to avoid that is to call the wrapped program with an absolute path. A fancier way is to examine `$PATH` manually and skip your own script (as identified with `$0`).

```
find_command () {
  script_dir={1%/*}; command_name=${1##*/}
  real_command=
  IFS=':'; set +f
  for d in $PATH; do
    if [ "$d" = "$script_dir" ]; then continue; fi
    if [ -x "$d/$command_name" ]; then real_command="$d/command_name" break; fi
  done
  set -f; unset IFS
  [ -n "$real_command" ]
}
find_command "$0" || {
  echo 1>&2 "$0: cannot find underlying command in \$PATH=$PATH"
  exit 2
}
exec "$0" -m32 "$@"
```

Some additional tips:

- Use `exec` if you don't need the shell anymore once you've launched the real command. Some shells know to do this as an optimization, but not all.
- Use `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash` unless you're using bash features. On many systems, `sh` is a leaner, faster shell than `bash`, with fewer features but wrapper scripts rarely need these advanced features.