# How to execute a command/script after a specific command was executed?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zsh, flatpak

I have a tiny script which generates aliases for the execution of flatpak packages (to make flatpaks somehow usable from the command line). When I run this command by hand, everything works fine.

But instead of always executing this command by hand after each flatpak install/update/remove I want my script to be executed automatically every time after the flatpak command was invoked.

So, to make a bit more clear effectively I need commands `flatpak *` to be rewritten to `flatpak * && ~/my_script.sh`.

Bonus: How could I restrict this function to only call the script if `flatpak install` or `flatpak remove` was called but not when `flatpak list` for example?

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Actually off-topic (though solving your actual problem, I guess), are you aware flatpak's do have "binaries" (actually the shell scripts/wrappers, you talk about) installed by default in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/`, e.g. `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/fake.application.Identity`. (The exact path may depend on your exact installation, e.g. if installed as a user, but it's there already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `alias` and add that to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias flatpak='flatpak_(){ flatpak "$@" && ~/my_script.sh; }; flatpak_'
```

To only execute `my_script` if first argument was `install` or `remove`:

```
alias flatpak='flatpak_(){ flatpak "$@" && [[ "$1" = install || "$1" = remove ]] && ~/my_script.sh; }; flatpak_'
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect! I am always unsure about how to use bash functions correctly.  
Just one follow up question: How could I restrict this function to only call the script if `flatpak install` or `flatpak remove` was called but not when `flatpak list` for example.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: It seems like that doesn't totally work. I always get \`zsh: parse error near `|'` when executing flatpak now.

Comment: I removed the regex and changed to a "normal" test, now it should be more portable ;-)

Comment: I somehow expected something like this :) Anyway, the new versions works perfectly fine, thank you!

Comment: Why create an alias instead of a function?

Comment: Simply, because a function does not work for that use-case. `flatpak(){flatpak "$@"; ...; }` would create an infinite loop when running. You could choose a different name, but then you need to change your behavior how to run the command.

Comment: Defining an alias is needlessly complicated. Putting it in `.bashrc` would have no effect on scripts. The return code is wrong if the first argument is not `install` or `remove`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' While there might exist better options I don't think a Downvote is necessary?! I did not know about `command ...`. Thanks for that I could learn something new again.

Answer (score 1):

Define a wrapper function in your `.zshrc`:

```
flatpak () {
  command flatpak "$@" && ~/my_script.sh
}
```

The `command` builtin tells the shell to invoke the external command called `flatpak` (found in `$PATH`) rather than calling the function recursively. `"$@"` is replaced by the list of arguments passed to `flatpak`.

This works in all sh-like shells (dash, bash, ksh, zsh, …) (provided you arrange to make the function accessible). Note that the function will not be defined in scripts: if you want the wrapper to be used in scripts, you need to define the function near the top of the script, or else put your wrapper in a separate script that's on the `$PATH` ahead of where the real `flatpak` is; see [Simple wrapper scripts spawning 100s of bash processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23334/simple-wrapper-scripts-spawning-100s-of-bash-processes).

To only run the script after certain commands, and as before only on success:

```
flatpak () {
  command flatpak "$@" &&
  case $1 in
    install|remove) ~/my_script.sh;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, where do you put the wrapper function? I thought OP wants to run `flatpak install ...`  from terminal. At least that is what I read from *"I want my script to be executed automatically every time after the flatpak command was invoked."*.

Comment: @pLumo Oh, right, thanks. I'd originally misread the question as being from a script, and forgot to update the opening sentence.